# Spring WS (DefaultWsdl11Definition) HTTP status code with void

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws, http-status-codes

We have a (working) SOAP web service based on Spring WS with *DefaultWsdl11Definition*.

This is basically what it looks like:

```java
@Endpoint("name")
public class OurEndpoint {

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "somenamespace", localPart = "localpart")
    public void onMessage(@RequestPayload SomePojo pojo) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

It is wired in Spring and it is correctly processing all of our SOAP requests. The only problem is that the method returns a **202 Accepted**. This is *not* what the caller wants, he'd rather have us return **204 No Content** (or if that is not possible an empty **200 OK**).

Our other endpoints have a valid response object, and do return **200 OK**. It seems void causes **202** when **204** might be more appropriate?

Is it possible to change the response code in Spring WS? We can't seem to find the correct way to do this.

Things we tried and didn't work:

- Changing the return type to:

  - HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT
  - org.w3c.dom.Element <- not accepted
- Adding *@ResponseStatus* <- this is for MVC, not WS

Any ideas?

Comment: 202 means that the request has been accepted but processing isn't finished. I guess this is due to the `void` return type, the `DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter` then doesn't call the `handleMethodReturnValue` because there is nothing to handle. I guess the easiest way to return a 200 (or whatever) is to create a custom `SoapMessageDispatcher` and reimplement the `receive` method. You probably would need to copy the whole class(hierarchy) as the class is quite closed (final methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When finding a proper solutions we've encountered some ugly problems:

- Creating custom adapters/interceptors is problematic because the *handleResponse* method isn't called by Spring when you don't have a response (void)
- Manually setting the status code doesn't work because *HttpServletConnection* keeps a boolean **statusCodeSet** which doesn't get updated

But luckily we managed to get it working with the following changes:

```java
/**
 * If a web service has no response, this handler returns: 204 No Content
 */
public class NoContentInterceptor extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {
        if (!messageContext.hasResponse()) {
            TransportContext tc = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
            if (tc != null && tc.getConnection() instanceof HttpServletConnection) {
                HttpServletConnection connection = ((HttpServletConnection) tc.getConnection());
                // First we force the 'statusCodeSet' boolean to true:
                connection.setFaultCode(null);
                // Next we can set our custom status code:
                connection.getHttpServletResponse().setStatus(204);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next we need to register this interceptor, this can be easily done using Spring's XML:

```xml
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.something.NoContentInterceptor"/>
</sws:interceptors>
```

A big thanks to @m-deinum for pointing us in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what I wrote in the comments it is possibly the easiest to create a delegation kind of solution.

```java
public class DelegatingMessageDispatcher extends MessageDispatcher {
    private final WebServiceMessageReceiver delegate;

    public DelegatingMessageDispatcher(WebServiceMessageReceiver delegate) {
         this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void receive(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
        this.delegate.receive(messageContext);
        if (!messageContext.hasResponse()) {
            TransportContext tc = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
            if (tc != null && tc.getConnection() instanceof HttpServletConnection) {
                ((HttpServletConnection) tc.getConnection()).getHttpServletResponse().setStatus(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to configure a bean named `messageDispatcher` which would wrap the default `SoapMessageDispatcher`.

```java
@Bean
public MessageDispatcher messageDispatcher() {
    return new DelegatingMessageDispatcher(soapMessageDispatcher());
}

@Bean
public MessageDispatcher soapMessageDispatcher() {
    return new SoapMessageDispatcher();
}
```

Something like that should do the trick. Now when response is created (In the case of a void return type), the status as you want is send back to the client.

Comment: The solution provided doesn't quite work, the main reason is the 'statusCodeSet' field in HttpServletConnection is false (even when we set it manually). But you've greatly helped me in the right direction, I'll post a working version here soon!

Answer (score 0):

To override the afterCompletion method really helped me out in the exact same situation. And for those who use code based Spring configuration, here´s how one can add the interceptor for a specific endpoint.

Annotate the custom interceptor with @Component, next register the custom interceptor to a WsConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class EndpointConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

/**
 * Add our own interceptor for the specified WS endpoint.
 * @param interceptors
 */
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    interceptors.add(new PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor(
            new NoContentInterceptor(),
            "NAMESPACE",
            "LOCAL_PART"
    ));
 }
}
```

NAMESPACE and LOCAL_PART should correspond to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever wanted to set custom HTTP status when returning non-void response, here is solution:

[Spring Boot WS-Server - Custom Http Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319318/spring-boot-ws-server-custom-http-status/67366575#67366575)